# Hide facebook notifications inside app?

Tags: notifications, facebook, spam

May be I mismatched a forum, but I hope, you can help me.
I don't like social networks and facebook especially. But I need to use it. I've installed official application and I'm received annoying notifications like these, from picture
[image: screenshot]

Can I unsubscribe from these or change a setting or do I need to find some way to delete these one by one?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for specific Facebook instructions.

Comment: You are right, I can't argue. But I still hoping for an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These [notifications are controlled by Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/327994277286267). Regrettably they can not all be turned off

> ### What is People You May Know?
>
> People You May Know are people on Facebook that you might know. **We show you people** based on mutual friends, work and education information, networks you’re part of, contacts you’ve imported and many other factors.

I recommend giving [Facebook feedback](https://www.facebook.com/help/suggestions) about this behaviour and why you wish to turn it off.

Comment: If it is impossible to turn off this spam, it is good enough reason to forgot about facebook forever. Thanks a lot, I'll try. Good luck!